# How to remove an element that has been modified by outerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an element in the DOM that I update its HTML using [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) property, but I can't remove it using a method like [`remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove).

```html
<div id="element">Element</div>
<div id="remove">Removed element</div>
```

```js
const element = document.getElementById("element");
const removedElement = document.getElementById("remove");

element.outerHTML = "<div>First</div>";
element.remove();
removedElement.remove();
```

In my example, `element` gets updated using `outerHTML`, but I can't remove it using `remove()` method while I can remove `removedElement` easily.

That's not expected. Am I missing something in the specification? I've looked in W3C, but it's very advanced for me.

And, MDN doesn't mention anything about that (unless I have missed something). I'm OK with either other methods to update HTML content or to remove elements from the DOM, but I'd love to know the original reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML):

> while the element will be replaced in the document, the variable whose outerHTML property was set will still hold a reference to the original element

The `element` variable still contains `<div id="element">Element</div>`, but is no longer in the document tree, so calling `remove()` has no effect.

```js
const element = document.getElementById("element");
element.outerHTML = "<div>First</div>";
console.log(element); // still has original contents
```

```html
<div id="element">Element</div>
```

To keep the reference to the new element, consider using `Element#replaceWith` and `document.createElement`.

```js
const element = document.getElementById("element");
const newEl = Object.assign(document.createElement('div'), {textContent: 'First'});
element.replaceWith(newEl);
console.log(element);
console.log(newEl);
newEl.remove();
```

```html
<div id="element">Element</div>
```

Comment: Great, I didn't notice that it's no longer in the document tree. So in such cases, how can I remove that element from the DOM?

Comment: @LightningMcQueen Consider working with `document.createElement` and `Element#replaceWith` instead.